# Can a window seal be too tight?

Tags: windows, sealing

I just added Tesa Moll (https://www.tesa.com/en/consumer/tesamoll-p-profile.html) to my windows, because they didn't really shut tight.

Now it is really tight and quite a  bit of strength is needed to open and shut the window.

My questions are:
How tight is too tight?
Can I damage the  window if I insert too thick sealing?

I live in Germany and the window frames are made of plastic. There are 3 bolts on the side of the handle that shut the window close when turning the lever.

Comment: Since it's a surface mounted product you should be able to reposition the seal to reduce pressure on the window frame without significantly compromising it's effectiveness as a sealant.

Comment: ↑ though you need to balance that against its propensity to crush & remain crushed, over time. Aim for 'stiff but not impossible to close', otherwise next year you'll need to re-do it.